# Getting sum of averages in a django queryset

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-orm

```
def get_queryset(self):
    current_academic_year = get_current_academic_year()
    domains = Domain.objects.all()
    start_date = self.request.query_params.get("start_date", current_academic_year.start_date)
    end_date = self.request.query_params.get("end_date",  current_academic_year.end_date)
    queryset = Account.objects.annotate(**{
        f"domain_overall_{domain.uuid}": Avg(
            "assessed_from__accountevaluationresult__calculated_rating",
            filter=Q(
                assessed_from__updated__range=(start_date, end_date)
            ) & Q(assessed_from__domain=domain)
        )
        for domain in domains
    }).annotate(**{f"domains_total": ~query~
    })
```

There are five domains.
Here I got 5 key-value pairs with certain calculated values for each domain.
I need to get the sum of those values from the first annotation, but have no idea how to retrieve it in continuous annotations.

Response I need in a json must be like this:

- "domain_overall_8939396e-d0a9-4c87-afe1-ae3a4660d84b": 2,
- "domain_overall_786a99b4-38fd-4b60-ac91-5a09f007db32": 1,
- "domain_overall_a1f503a7-5e77-47ee-a812-7ae1fb4e8a84": 1,
- "domain_overall_4c55b38b-8471-48d1-bc43-323570b290a4": 1,
- "domain_overall_6ec0c80b-5afe-4ac2-8c07-0fff5c4f023c": 3,
- "domains_total": 8,

What is the best approach/solution here?

Answer (score 1):

Because you want to fetch all averages from db anyway, I would calculate the sum of all values in Python, after fetching the data.

First, lets simplify the queryset:

```py
queryset = Account.objects.filter(assessed_from__domain__in=domains).annotate(
    domain=F('assessed_from__domain'),
    average=Avg("assessed_from__accountevaluationresult__calculated_rating",
                filter=Q(assessed_from__updated__range=(start_date, end_date)
).values('domain', 'average')
```

This can be done using vanilla Python like:

```py
total_sum = sum(d.average for d in queryset)
```

This can also be done faster using Pandas, like:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(queryset)
total_sum = df['average'].agg('sum')
```

With this approach, you can also serialize it to JSON easier:

```py
df = df.append({"domain": "domains_totals", "average": total_sum}, ignore_index=True)
df = df.set_index("domain")
json_str = df['average'].to_json()
```

Comment: Thank you for very clear explanation. I'll try this approach.